# Rspec how to test class call to singleton class method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

A class `User` has a call `has_one_time_password(encrypted: true)`
I want to test that User class has that call.

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
#...
has_one_time_password(encrypted: true)
#..
end
```

I have tried

```
expect(User).to receive(:has_one_time_password).with(encrypted: true)
```

but I was getting message that there message `expected: 1, received: 0`

Comment: As already mentioned in an Answer: once you reference User the class method is loaded. Hence your assertion fails.

But much more important: what should this test? Does not make much sense IMHO to test if this method is called.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that at the time your `expect(User)...` above was run, the `class User < ApplicationRecord ... end` was already loaded into memory because of your **rails_helper.rb** which has a line at the top of it:

`require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)`.

Therefore, you won't be able to catch it unless you load it manually like the following:

```
expect(User).to receive(:has_one_time_password).with(encrypted: true)
require 'user'
```

*P.S. Haven't tested this yet. Furthermore, personally, I would rather test the "behaviour" and not test the code itself, so perhaps I'll write a test on what behaviour does`has_one_time_password` actually do*